# timer function cannot pass to button event

Tags: vb.net, timer, filestream, fastreport

I am working on a project that gets the text box index line by line.
So when I click the button, Start reads the index of text and listbox prints it. At the end I will make the listbox visibility false then the index of text displays in fastreport. What I am trying to overcome is timer doesn't run.

On the other hand, assume I have 10 collections of line in my text file. By using ReadLine property, compiler stops due to 11th element. How can I cope with that issue.

Here is my code.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim _report As Report
Dim val As StreamReader
Dim fs As FileStream
Dim second As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    fs = New FileStream("tf.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    val = New StreamReader(fs)

    Timer1.Interval = 5000

End Sub

Private Sub FileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FileButton.Click

    If (ListBox1.SelectedIndex) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(val.ReadLine)
    End If
    Timer1.Start()

    '_report.Load("file.frx")
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ListBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString

    second = second + 1
    If second >= 5 Then
        Timer1.Stop()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're doing. The phrase, "gets the text box index line by line", is confusing. I think you need to describe what you're trying to do in more abstract terms.

Comment: It means that I have 10 lines in the text file such as (name1, 5) ,(name2, 5) until (name10, 5). What I want to do is when I click the FileButton, it displays each index in the listbox. As long as I click the FileButton, it runs until at the end of the list. However, I want to use timer.

Comment: So read a text file, line-by-line, one line each second, and add each line to a textbox as it is read?

Comment: Yeah thats true. one line each 5 seconds.

Comment: Your Timer interval is set to 5 seconds. If you want it to tick every second then you should set it to 1000 and the readline should probably be in the timer tick sub if you want to read a line every second

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-WinForms"):

```
File _
    .ReadAllLines("tf.txt") _
    .ToObservable() _
    .Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)), Function (line, n) line) _
    .ObserveOn(ListBox1) _
    .Subscribe(Sub (line) ListBox1.Items.Add(line))
```